# How is a delocalised state realised and what is its wavefunction?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, interferometry

Gravitationally induced entanglement experiments aim at studying the quantum nature of gravity trough the interaction of a delocalised particle state with another system. The various papers on the topic that I found (e.g. https://arxiv.org/abs/2205.09013 ,    https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.06036 , https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.06050 and references therein) allude to the fact that these superpositions are already achievable in a laboratory with nanocrystals or similar small mass systems. From the experimental point of view I would like to understand:

How are these delocalised states and their gradual recombination realised in practice?

Other than the practical methods one thing I couldn't find in any papers (or anywhere else really) is how we would describe the wavefunction of such a state in any one basis.
Of course in the description of GIE experiments the knowledge of the Hamiltonian is enough to infere the amount of interference one would expect to find after recombination, but how could we describe a state in a superposition of position states as a wavefunction during this process?

I suppose the two questions are related since an understanding of how these states are realized might give an idea on how the state can be described in terms of a wavefuntion.